# IQueryable doesn't work for not equals

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iqueryable

The code I use to filter my objects is like:

```
var dynamicdataentrances = db.DynamicDataEntrances.OrderByDescending(d => d.ID)
                                                  .AsQueryable();
if (TypeID != null)
    dynamicdataentrances = 
        dynamicdataentrances.Where(d => d.DetailPageID == TypeID).AsQueryable();
if (RegionID != null)
    dynamicdataentrances = 
        dynamicdataentrances.Where(d => d.RegionID == RegionID).AsQueryable();
if (ShiftGroupID != null)
    dynamicdataentrances = 
        dynamicdataentrances.Where(d => d.ShiftPlan.ShiftGroupID == ShiftGroupID)
                            .AsQueryable();
```

And it works without any problems. However, filtering the objects according to "Workflow State" doesn't work. The code for it is like:

```
foreach (var wfs in workflowstates)
{
    if (Request[wfs.ID.ToString()] != wfs.ID.ToString())
      dynamicdataentrances = 
        dynamicdataentrances.Where(d => d.WorkflowStateRelation.WorkflowStateID
                                          != wfs.ID).AsQueryable();
}
```

As you can figure out, I use checkboxes for filtering; If Workflow State's checkbox isn't checked, I get the objects whose Workflow State isn't equal to unchecked one. I debugged the lines, foreach and if blocks are working correct, but the query doesn't work accordingly, it keeps getting all the objects. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

If I turn my object collection to **List** before the Workflow State filtering, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **List** it works, because the objects are already in the memory and not equal ones are ruled out for every non-checked state.

However, with **IQueryable** the objects are on the database, and the query gets all the objects, because they aren't ruled out from the list on each step.

I got the solution with:

```
var unCheckedStates = new List<int>();
foreach (var wfs in workflowstates)
{
    if (Request[wfs.ID.ToString()] != wfs.ID.ToString())
    {
        unCheckedStates.Add(wfs.ID);
    }
}
dynamicdataentrances = 
    dynamicdataentrances.Where(d => !unCheckedStates
                        .Contains(d.WorkflowStateRelation.WorkflowStateID))
                        .AsQueryable();
```